# Насколько тяжело написать лингвистический словарь на android

Tags: android, sqlite

Допустим англо-русский, и можете написать структуру такого приложения, буду очень благодарен, мне очень нужно

Comment: от 1 дня до года, всё зависит от к-ва фенечек:)

Comment: Я оцениваю одна таблица, поля: ID, langID, word, description. этого вполне достаточно. Или две таблицы одна англо-русская другая наоборот.

Comment: Aandroid Studio - средство разработки,  программы пишут не на ней, а в ней - для андроид, в основном, на Java. Это тоже самое, что спрашивать, тяжело ли написать рассказ на Блокноте.

Answer (score 1):

Вам нужна будет база данных со словами и преводами для них. У каждого слова - свой ID, как и у перевода. Сводная таблица ассоциирует ID слова к ID перевода. Ввод слова - старт JOIN запроса - найти слово в базе и взять его ID, взять из сводной таблицы список ID переводов, сделать выборку переводов из таблицы переводов для списка ID.

Для добавления нового слова и(или) перевода - просто новую запись делаем в соответствующую таблицу и ассоциируем в сводной таблице.

Для работы с БД подойдёт SQLite ([здесь вводная статья](http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/sqlite/android-sqlite.php))

если языков много - создаём таблицу названий языков и добавляем их ID в таблицу переводов. А дальше в JOIN запросе фильтруем по ID языка нужные записи.

Рекомендую не полениться и создать более-менее нормализованную БД. Это позволит проще и с меньшей болью наращивать функционал приложения. Вариант с множеством языков тогда лучше будет реализовать через введение ещё двух сводных таблиц: перевод-язык и слово-язык. Тогда структура таблиц будет такой: таблица языков, таблица слов, таблица переводов, сводная таблица слова-языки, сводная таблица переводы-языки, сводная таблица слово-перевод.

Comment: Поскольку у одного слова (и в ту и в другую строну) может быть несколько переводов, здесь уместна связь многие ко многим

Comment: она реализуется в сводных таблицах, Вы совершенно правы.